# Linked Server Test Connection Not Working (SQL Server to Oracle Database)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

**Database Versions:**
SSMS: 17.9,
Oracle: 19.3

We are trying to establish a linked server connection to our production Oracle DB (hosted by another team) that uses SSL. The LS was created, however our test connection attempts always return this:

`Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "CDWRP201_TCPS". OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "CDWRP201_TCPS" returned message "Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-28759". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)`

I read that this meant "failure to open file" and could be caused by insufficient wallet permissions so I gave our users full access to the files (not sure if this is recommended). I did the same for the ewallet, ORA files, and even their parent folders but still no success.

What's weird is that test connections work for our non-SSL connections, which use the same tnsnames.ora file. We have no problems connecting to the Oracle DB using `tnsping` and `sqlplus` as well.

I'm struggling with this because my experience with Oracle and SSMS linked servers are few to none and feel like I've hit a dead end. Any direction you can give will be very much appreciated. I'm happy to provide more details if needed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What options were used to create the wallet? What is the `WALLET_LOCATION` value in sqlnet.ora on the client? Is the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable set with the path to the directory containing sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora for the user or service account initiating the connection?

Comment: Hi @pmdba,

1. We used `orapki` to create the wallet and included an `-auto_login_local` parameter during creation.
2. `Wallet_Location` is in C:\app\oracle\wallet, which was created prior to #1.
3. We don't have a `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable. The only variable that indicated Oracle was our `PATH` and the value saved was `C:\Oracle\x64\product\19.0.0\client_64\bin`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First try recreating the wallet with just the `-auto_login` option and not `-auto_login_local`. Sometimes that option doesn't work well on Windows.

Comment: Hi @pmdba, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and created a new wallet using `-auto_login` + changed the wallet locations in sqlnet and tnsnames. Still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have TWO problems.

First, your call to oracle returned ORA-28795.  AS others are focusing on, that results from a failure to open a wallet. However, rather than looking for permissions issues, I'd note the second error ...

The "*Error while trying to retrieve text for error*"  indicates that your ORACLE_HOME (for the oracle client being used my msssql) is not correctly set.  When the call received the  ORA-28759, it needed to find the error message file to be able to properly report it.  But with improper ORACLE_HOME it was unable to locate the message file.

And it very well might be the case that the invalid ORACLE_HOME is also the root cause of the ORA-28759.  I've not much expderince with walllets, but it seems reasonable that it needs ORACLE_HOME to locate the wallet, just as it needs it to locate the message file ... and a bunch of other stuff.  In any event, get ORACLE_HOME set correctly and you will get more informative diagnostics/error messages on your ORA-28795.

You said yourself that "The only variable that indicated Oracle was our PATH".  You need to also set ORACLE_HOME.  If your oracle PATH is 'C:\Oracle\x64\product\19.0.0\client_64\bin', then your ORACLE_HOME should be 'C:\Oracle\x64\product\19.0.0\client_64'

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for responding. When I checked our system variables, I first thought that maybe it was because we didn't have ORACLE_HOME set up in the first place that we're getting this error. After adding it however the situation remained the same.

Comment: "remained the same"?   Do you still get the "Error while trying to retrieve text for error"?  If so, then you still don't have ORACLE_HOME set correctly.